# Getting a user's Facebook pic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I get a users Facebook picture in a Rails app without fully integrating Facebook Connect into Authlogic?

Answer (score 1):

Without scraping Facebook (which violates their ToS) you would have to use their APIs.

This would mean you'd either have to use their Facebook Connect platform, or create an app and have all your site users participate in it (which would really beat around the push.)

http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect looks fairly simple to setup and use.

I'm not sure if it's tied into Facebook Connect, but they also have a sharing platform (meant to add, in essence, a 'share' button to your site.)
This may give you enough access to get the user's profile picture if they are currently logged in.